# TP Link router WiFi to LAN Bridge?

Tags: router, home-networking, bridge

I have a pc without a network card in the back of the house and the router in the front. I got an old router and wanted to make a bridge that converts the wifi signal into ethernet to be able to access the internet at this pc. I have only found Wifi to Wifi bridges so I hope anybody has an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an "Access point client. If your router does not include this functionality you should be able to flash ddwrt onto it to enable that. You will want to plug the switch into a LAN port and disable dhcp on it.

If you already have WIFI you can use this to roam seemlessly by setting the same SSID, password and security type.

Comment: I was able to deactivate DHCP, but as I try to set the security to WPA2, it won't let me procede to saving until I add a Radius Server IP